# Factorization of parabolic subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup of an algebraic group $G$. How to prove that $P = L_P U_P$? Here $L_P$ is the Levi of $P$ and $U_P$ is the unipotent radical of $P$. Thank you very much.

Edit: I think that if 
$$
P=\left( \begin{matrix} * & * & * & * \\
* & * & * & * \\
0 & 0 & * & * \\
0 & 0 & * & * \end{matrix} \right),
$$
then
$$
U_P=\left( \begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & * & * \\
0 & 1 & * & * \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right),
$$

$$
L_P=\left( \begin{matrix} 
* & * & 0 & 0 \\
* & * & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & * & * \\
0 & 0 & * & * \end{matrix} \right).
$$
Is this true? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Shaun, I don't understand much about $U_P$ and $L_P$. For example, let $$  P = \left( \begin{matrix} * & * & 0 & 0 \\ * & * & 0 & 0 \\ * & * & * & * \\ * & * & * & * \end{matrix} \right) $$. What is $U_P$ and $L_P$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof just uses the root subgroup structure of $G$ and the fact that up to conjugation every parabolic is a standard parabolic, so we need only prove this when $P = P_I$ for some set $I$ of simple roots.

If $R$ is the root system and $I \subseteq \Delta$ is some subset of simple roots then let $R_I = R \cap \mathbb ZI$.  Let $T$ be the torus and for any root $\alpha \in R$ let $U_\alpha$ be the root subgroup corresponding to $\alpha$.  Now $P_I$ is generated by $T$ and root subgroups $U_\alpha$ where $\alpha \in R \setminus R_I^-$.  $U_I$ is generated by the root subgroups $U_\alpha$ where $\alpha \in R_I^+$ and $L_I$ is generated by $U_\alpha$ where $\alpha \in R \setminus R_I$.

You need to show that $U_I$ is the unipotent radical of $P_I$ and that $L_I$ is reductive, but once you have that you just observe that $L_IU_I$ is generated by $T$ and root subgroups $U_\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is in
$$R_I^+ \cup (R \setminus R_I) = R \setminus R_I^-.$$
But that's what generates $P_I$ so $L_IU_I = P_I$.